# What is the best wording for an admin setting that changes a users view?

Tags: wording, settings

**Background:**

I am working with a team on an application where there is an admin user who can edit websites. In this, there is are preconfigured widgets an admin can add to their page. One of them is an list of events.

In the event list widget, the admin can select how they want to display their list of events to the user. Currently, they have 3 options:

1. List only
2. Calendar only
3. List and calendar

**Problem:**

If an admin user adds another widget next to the list of events in the same row and the admin has selected to show the list and calendar view, the list and calendar in the widget will be compressed. We are using media queries, but since the overall screen size hasn't changed, they don't have any effect.

**Solution:**

To solve this, we'd like to let the admin pick what view they want the user to see by default in the settings panel provided when the admin begins editing their site. The admin would be allowed to show the calendar or list view by default and the user would be able to toggle between the two.

**Question:**

What wording should be used in the settings panel title to let the admin user know they are going to change how their user will see the widget? Currently, we have `Default View` with a dropdown that says `Calendar` and `List` but I think that's a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can and should ask your users if the "Default View: [Calendar, List]" selection is unclear. My hunch is that it will be alright. If they're modifying widgets, the concept of a widget having a "default view" shouldn't seem terribly unexpected.

If you'd like to consider a different approach, you could:

- When an administrator is viewing a non-default view, show a clickable option for administrators to "Set as widget's default view" or something similar.
- When an administrator is viewing the default view, show "✔ This is the default view" as plain text.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzIp0M.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Certainly play with the wording, but I think this should make some sense.

Comment: Yes! Ask your viewers. You just need 3 or 5 people to test with.

Answer (score 1):

Many online events/calendar websites call your "list view" the "Agenda View" (search for Wordpress calendar plugins). Google used to call it Agenda View (in their calendar) but has changed it to Schedule View.

I understand what List View is (as well as Agenda View). But if you wish to design for what is already commonly used -- it appears Agenda View is most popular.

If you're worried about being too ambiguous (and you can afford more letters in the UI), add the words: View As ...

As for the Admin, the heading: Default View is very appropriate and I would not change that.